# Перенаправление с параметром

Tags: .htaccess

Как сделать редирект со страниц `/name/detail.php-ID=1234` на `/name/detail.php?ID=1234`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule /name/detail.php-ID=(\d+) /name/detail.php?ID=$1
```

так ?